# Does 'Add-MpPreference' powershell command used for changing Defender settings support Regular expressions in folder paths?

Tags: windows, powershell, virtual-machine, windows-defender

I have setup a Kubernetes cluster to deploy my cloud application and the application pods/services are deployed on several Windows nodes. Defender antivirus is installed on all of these nodes to scan the folders belonging to the application.

Due this scanning, the nodes have been utilizing high CPU and the performance of nodes have been declining. I want to add some application folders on nodes to Defender exclusions and avoid them from scanning. For this I'm using 'Add-MpPreference -ExclusionProcess <path_to_process>' command.

While the command has been working fine when I just include a single folder path to the process. I wanted to know if this command support adding regular expressions in the 'ExclusionProcess' parameter?
Ex:  Add-MpPreference -ExclusionProcess 'C:/Program Files/*'
In this example, does the command exclude all the folders under Program Files from scanning?

I tried executing the command mentioned in example above with regular expressions.
The command executed successfully. But I'm not sure if the exclusions are really applied on Defender. How to check this?